# Measuring the effect of a variable across a threshold

Tags: regression, skewness, threshold

Within my data I am trying to assess whether the response variable increases as we move across different thresholds. The difficulty is that the response variable also increases exponentially as a function of our independent variable - so I need to measure whether it increases "more than it should" in these threshold regions.

My data is also heavily skewed - I have considered both subsampling and over sampling but am concerned that doing so will mask the subtle effect of these threshold changes.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: I should say that it only increases approximately exponentially - it isn't a perfect fit

Comment: Can you post some plots?

Comment: Would it make sense to curve fit the data to some approximating exponential function, and then subtract that to remove the effect of the exponential increase?

Answer (score 1):

You can get turn the approximate exponential increase into a linear increase by taking log of the DV. Then you can a) model a linear fit and graphically see what happens at the thresholds, b) Model a spline fit with predetermined knots and see what happens at the knots and c) Model a spline fit without predetermined knots and see if the knots show up where you thought they would.